# Problems to configure FTP server

Tags: ubuntu, networking, ftp, vsftpd

Im try configure Vsftpd in Ubuntu installed on a computer that works as Server in my office. This server have the next local IP: 192.168.1.20
I need that, others pc (inside the LAN) connect via FTP with the Server.
After install Vsftpd, i create an test user and add to ftp group:

```
# adduser --home /var/www --no-create-home --shel /bin/bash devftp
# addgroup devftp ftp
```

But, when i try connect via Filezilla to the server addres, with the user "devftp", the connection fails with error:

> "ECONNREFUSED - Connection refused by server".

Any ideas ?.

Comment: Did you set `local_enable=YES` in `/etc/vsftpd.conf`?

Comment: I recommend you to look at your vsftpd.log file. You'll probably see the issue, and it will be easier to solve.